# I can't find the database file in SDcard

Tags: sqlite

I used this code to create database in SDcard

```
public class DBConnect  {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBConnect() {
        db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/db.db3",null);
    }
```

My app works well, I can save everything in Listview. But when I open DDMS, I can't find the database file anywhere, the SD card is empty. Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, ok.

I think that the default path of the databases is something like this.

/data/data/yourpackage/databases

So, maybe you can use one of this two ways.

First way.

```
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String databaseName = "mydatabase.db";
        Path databasePath = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName);
```

Second way.

```
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        File databaseFile = new File(context.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/databases/mydatabase.db");
```

Let me know if this help you.

Comment: I am new to Android, so can you tell me the 2 codes above mean? Are they for creating database in my package path? In that case, I checked my package path and found no database either. And I want to save to SDcard, not the default path.

Comment: The codes that I posted are for know if the database is created on the default path. The first way must return the path of your database. Maybe you can make a copy of the original database and paste it on the SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you save the database on the SD Card?

Comment: I'm not sure.That is why I am asking :D. I can save and load objects on listview when I reopen the app, so I am just sure that there is a database somewhere but I can't find it :(